# Why does the Django filter() adds items instead of removing them?

Tags: python, django

I'm very curious about the filter() method behaviour.
I read in the documentation that they can be chained. Ok let's try:

```
# Returns a Queryset of 2 objects : [<CliProfile: Sven>, <CliProfile: David>]
res = SomeClass.objects.all()

# Returns a Queryset of 3 objects : [<CliProfile: Sven>, <CliProfile: Sven>, <CliProfile: David>]
res2 = res.filter(some_attr__gte=a_datetime_object)
```

How is this possible? If the initial queryset contains 2 objects, how is it possible that a filter() method makes this queryset grow?

Comment: Is `some_attr` on a related object?

Comment: Yes. The full line is `res.filter(card__points__created__gte=...)` (`Points`class has a `benef_card = models.ForeignKey(Card, related_name='points'`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your filter applies to *related objects*; for `<CliProfile: Sven>` two such objects matched, so that object is listed twice.

Add a [`.distinct()` call](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct):

```
res2 = res.filter(some_attr__gte=a_datetime_object).distinct()
```

As the documentation for `.distinct()` states:

> By default, a `QuerySet` will not eliminate duplicate rows. In practice, this is rarely a problem, because simple queries such as `Blog.objects.all()` don’t introduce the possibility of duplicate result rows. **However, if your query spans multiple tables, it’s possible to get duplicate results when a `QuerySet` is evaluated**. That’s when you’d use `distinct()`.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: By the way, to achieve why I wanted, I was using the bad way of filtering (I didn't need to chain them but to: `filter(expr1, expr2)`). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships